# jQuery execute function on each carousel slide one at a time

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, svg, css-transitions, carousel

I am trying to run a function on each carousel slide one at a time for visual effect when each slide is visible (active).

The function adds a class to elements but it does not work on page load or the third slide (classes already added).

Working fine on the second carousel item.

```
$('#carousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function () {
    //console.log('slide event!');

    var arr = $('.carousel-item .text .st0').get();
    setTimeout(function delayMainFunction() {

        function random(arr) {
            if (!arr.length) {
                return;
            }
            var el = arr.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length), 1);
            $(el).attr('class', 'st0 transition-state');
            setTimeout(function () {
                random(arr);
            }, 10 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10))
        }
        random(arr);

    }, 600)
});
```

Should do this transition for each individual slide when visible (active).

[image: add class animation]

Codepen here http://codepen.io/Kerrys7777/pen/VpBvZW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I named your function...
This enables you to call it from anywhere.

So now, you can call it on load, like any other function.
And I added a setTimeout to remove the `transition-state` class for all letters of the SVG.

[**Your CodePen updated.**](http://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/yMRxKe)

```
console.clear();

$( document ).ready(function() {

  // Made it a named function
  var myAnimation = function(){
    console.log('slide event!');

    var arr = $('.carousel-item .text .st0').get();
    setTimeout(function delayMainFunction() {

      function random(arr) {
        if (!arr.length) {
          return;
        }
        var el = arr.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length), 1);
        $(el).attr('class', 'st0 transition-state');
        setTimeout(function () {
          random(arr);
        }, 10 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10))
      }
      random(arr);

      // Added setTimeout to remove the transition-state class from all SVG letters
      setTimeout(function() {
        $('.carousel-item .text .st0').removeClass('transition-state');
      },3500);

    }, 600);
  };


  $('.carousel').carousel({
    interval: 6000,
    pause: false
  })

  // To run on load
  myAnimation();

  // To bind the function the carousel event
  $(".carousel").on('slide.bs.carousel', myAnimation);
});
```

Comment: That is sick man! The class removal makes it even better than just working for the first loop through each item. The only tweak I made was  to increased the timeout (class removal). Your code comments are also really help. Thanks for your efforts. Win! Win!

Comment: lol!! I'm glad you love it ;) Your delayed addClass in random order is a real cool effect. Nice work! ;)

Comment: I did a graphic design course & developed a severe crush on Illustrator (SVG's). Trying to be creative with usage. I should do (attempt) something with http://snapsvg.io/demos/ when my JS skill improves. Thanks again Louys.